# Formatting errors that wrap multiple errors

Tags: go

In Go 1.20, we'll be able to [wrap multiple errors](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.20#errors). The following is a simple example where two errors, `err1` and `err2`, each wrap two lower level errors:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    err1_1 := errors.New("err1.1")
    err1_2 := errors.New("err1.2")
    err1 := fmt.Errorf("err1: %w", errors.Join(err1_1, err1_2))

    err2_1 := errors.New("err2.1")
    err2_2 := errors.New("err2.2")
    err2 := fmt.Errorf("err2: %w", errors.Join(err2_1, err2_2))

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", errors.Join(err1, err2))
}
```

The output from the above looks as follows:

```bash
err1: err1.1
err1.2
err2: err2.1
err2.2
```

I have to admit that I am not a fan of how this looks because there's no indication that `err1.2` is an inner error of `err1` and similar for `err2.2` with respect to `err2`. The following is one option that I find would make it clearer:

```bash
err1: err1.1
      err1.2
err2: err2.1
      err2.2
```

So my question is, do we have any error formatting options in Go 1.20 that I have overlooked? I have come across [this proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-error-printing.md) related to error formatting for Go2, but I assume we won't see that any time soon.

## Edit

As far as I can see, unwrapping the errors myself is not a reliable option because errors may be constructed in different ways. For example, an error may be wrapped as follows:

```golang
type CustomError struct {
    someValue string
    wrappedErr error
}

func (err *CustomError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("custom error %s: %s", someValue, wrappedErr )
}

func (err *CustomError) Unwrap() error {
    return err.wrappedErr 
}
```

Now consider the situation where `wrappedErr` is a joined error. I can see that it's possible to unwrap `CustomError` and detect that `wrappedErr` is a joined/multi error by checking if it implements `interface { Unwrap() []error }`. I think the issue is when one tries to reconstruct the error message. I can't see how one can get the text from `CustomError.Error()` while replacing the value of `wrapperErr` to a custom formatted joined error. Furthermore, while a joined error may have been constructed using `errors.Join` it could also have been constructed with a custom type that implements `interface { Unwrap() []error }` where again the formatting of the error message is an unknown.

I guess this issue is the whole purpose of the proposal that I linked above.

Comment: `errors.Join` is just a convenience method from what I can tell. You should be able to make your own implementation based on it. See https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/432898/11/src/errors/join.go

Comment: Interesting. I guess that works in the case where I control the code that creates the multi error, but not otherwise, e.g. third party library.

Comment: You could still create your own helper function to `Unwrap()` the error yourself and then print it to your liking. If you don't want to print right then and there, you could wrap everything with your own error type which gets the job done.

Comment: @Zyl, I edited my question to address your suggestion.

Comment: I haven't played with the new `errors` functionality, but [`golang.org/x/xerrors`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/xerrors) does provide error-formatting features that were left on the cutting floor for Go 1.13. Maybe it can help.